# Idea IntelliJ Dependancies issue with Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, dependencies, intellij-idea

I may have bitten off more than i can chew here. I've moved outside of my .net / visual studio comfort zone for the first time in order to play with the Android SDK. I'm (attempting) to use IntelliJ.

I have a single module project. I want to "reference" the google gson library. After hours of tooling around in the project structure dialog, googling, reading the IntelliJ help and laughing at my own ineptness I managed to at least get a successful build.

However when i deploy to the virtual device, I note the "logcat" shows:

> Could not find class
>   'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced
>   from method
>   com.example.HelloW$ClientThread.run

I'm assuming this is less to do with my code, and everything to do with how i ended up referencing the gson-1.7.1.jar file?

Can somebody tell me in the simplest terms how i add that dependancy successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding jar file to Dependencies is easy and you can find the details in the [official documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Make sure that the library scope is set to **Compile**.

Here is the sample showing "lib" library that contains a couple of jars added to the module dependencies:

[image: lib]

[image: dependencies]

Comment: Hmm.. yes between your answer and the doc link i think i'm there - at the moment i'm in that awkward phase trying to relate everything back to a visual studio concept. The IntelliJ approach is probably slightly more flexible but same outcome... thanks